# Failing coverage with babel-jest

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, babel-jest

### Intro

I'm moving from Vue^2 to Vue^3. Therefore I'm updating several dependencies, one of it is Jest.

Everything is working nice ... except code coverage collector.

### Context

Having this Vue component:

```js
// src/app/script.js
export default {
    name : 'app-layout',
    data : () => ({ foo : 'Welcome Foo!' })
};
```

This unitary test:

```js
// tests/unit/app.js;
import AppLayout     from '@/app';
import renderer      from '#/utils/renderer';

describe('app-layout', () =>
{
    describe('Definition', () =>
    {
        const { name = '', data } = AppLayout;
        it('Expect name is "app-layout"', () => expect(name).toBe('app-layout'));
        it('Expect data is a a function', () => expect(data).toBeInstanceOf(Function));
    });

    describe('Snapshots', () =>
    {
        it('Default has not been modified', async () =>
            expect(await renderer(AppLayout, null, true)).toMatchSnapshot());
    });
});
```

This `.babelrc.js` config:

```js
module.exports = {
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "modules": false,
                "shippedProposals": true
            }
        ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
        [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
            {
                "loose": false
            }
        ],
        [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods",
            {
                "loose": false
            }
        ],
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
    ],
    "env": {
        "test": {
            "plugins": [
                "istanbul"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This jest config:

```js
// config/jest/config.js
module.exports = {
    testRegex                   : 'tests/unit/[^_].+js$',
    collectCoverageFrom         : [
        'src/**/*.{mjs,js}',
        '!**/tests/**',
        '!**/node_modules/**',
        '!**/demo/**',
        '!**/mock.{mjs,js}'
    ],
    coverageDirectory           : '<rootDir>/coverage/unit',
    coveragePathIgnorePatterns  : [
        '/node_modules/',
        '/src/index.m?js'
    ],
    coverageThreshold           : {
        global : {
            branches   : 90,
            functions  : 90,
            lines      : 90,
            statements : -10
        }
    },
    moduleFileExtensions : ['js', 'json', 'mjs', 'vue'],
    moduleNameMapper     : {
        '^%/(.*)$' : `${root}/$1`,
        '^@/(.*)$' : '<rootDir>/src/$1',
        '^#/(.*)$' : '<rootDir>/tests/$1'
    },
    rootDir             : cwd,
    roots               : ['<rootDir>/src', '<rootDir>/tests'],
    setupFiles          : [
        resolver(path.join('tests', '_setup'))
    ],
    snapshotSerializers : ['jest-serializer-vue'],
    transform           : {
        '.m?js'         : 'babel-jest',
        '.vue'          : 'vue-jest',
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns : ['node_modules/(?!(?:@amjs))']
}
```

And this test script runner:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

const argv      = process.argv.slice(2);
const path      = require('path');

argv.push(
    '--coverage',
    '--no-cache',
    '--config',
    JSON.stringify(require(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'config', 'jest', 'config')), null, 4)
);

require('jest').run(argv);
```

### Results in ...

If I run the following `node scripts/test.js`

Outputs:

```
 PASS  tests/unit/app-layout.js
  app-layout
    Definition
      ✓ Expect name is "app-layout" (2 ms)
      ✓ Expect data is a a function
    Snapshots
      ✓ Default has not been modified (14 ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |       0 |      100 |       0 |       0 |                   
 script.js |       0 |      100 |       0 |       0 | 3                 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Jest: "global" coverage threshold for lines (90%) not met: 0%
Jest: "global" coverage threshold for functions (90%) not met: 0%
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   1 passed, 1 total
Time:        2.073 s
Ran all test suites.
```

But if I run `NODE_ENV=test node scripts/test.js`.
It outputs:

```
 PASS  tests/unit/app-layout.js
  app-layout
    Definition
      ✓ Expect name is "app-layout" (1 ms)
      ✓ Expect data is a a function
    Snapshots
      ✓ Default has not been modified (11 ms)

Running coverage on untested files...Failed to collect coverage from /Volumes/Projects/com.github/adhara/vue/fw/src/app/script.js
ERROR: Duplicate plugin/preset detected.
If you'd like to use two separate instances of a plugin,
they need separate names, e.g.

  plugins: [
    ['some-plugin', {}],
    ['some-plugin', {}, 'some unique name'],
  ]

Duplicates detected are:
[
  {
    "alias": "/Volumes/Projects/com.github/adhara/vue/fw/node_modules/babel-plugin-istanbul/lib/index.js",
    "dirname": "/Volumes/Projects/com.github/adhara/vue/fw",
    "ownPass": false,
    "file": {
      "request": "istanbul",
      "resolved": "/Volumes/Projects/com.github/adhara/vue/fw/node_modules/babel-plugin-istanbul/lib/index.js"
    }
  },
  {
    "alias": "/Volumes/Projects/com.github/adhara/vue/fw/node_modules/babel-plugin-istanbul/lib/index.js",
    "options": {
      "cwd": "/Volumes/Projects/com.github/adhara/vue/fw",
      "exclude": []
    },
    "dirname": "/Volumes/Projects/com.github/adhara/vue/fw",
    "ownPass": false,
    "file": {
      "request": "/Volumes/Projects/com.github/adhara/vue/fw/node_modules/babel-plugin-istanbul/lib/index.js",
      "resolved": "/Volumes/Projects/com.github/adhara/vue/fw/node_modules/babel-plugin-istanbul/lib/index.js"
    }
  }
]
STACK: Error: Duplicate plugin/preset detected.
If you'd like to use two separate instances of a plugin,
they need separate names, e.g.

  plugins: [
    ['some-plugin', {}],
    ['some-plugin', {}, 'some unique name'],
  ]

Duplicates detected are:
[
  {
    "alias": "/Volumes/Projects/com.github/adhara/vue/fw/node_modules/babel-plugin-istanbul/lib/index.js",
    "dirname": "/Volumes/Projects/com.github/adhara/vue/fw",
    "ownPass": false,
    "file": {
      "request": "istanbul",
      "resolved": "/Volumes/Projects/com.github/adhara/vue/fw/node_modules/babel-plugin-istanbul/lib/index.js"
    }
  },
  {
    "alias": "/Volumes/Projects/com.github/adhara/vue/fw/node_modules/babel-plugin-istanbul/lib/index.js",
    "options": {
      "cwd": "/Volumes/Projects/com.github/adhara/vue/fw",
      "exclude": []
    },
    "dirname": "/Volumes/Projects/com.github/adhara/vue/fw",
    "ownPass": false,
    "file": {
      "request": "/Volumes/Projects/com.github/adhara/vue/fw/node_modules/babel-plugin-istanbul/lib/index.js",
      "resolved": "/Volumes/Projects/com.github/adhara/vue/fw/node_modules/babel-plugin-istanbul/lib/index.js"
    }
  }
]
    at assertNoDuplicates (/Volumes/Projects/com.github/adhara/vue/fw/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:239:13)
    at createDescriptors (/Volumes/Projects/com.github/adhara/vue/fw/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:147:3)
    at createDescriptors.next (<anonymous>)
    at createPluginDescriptors (/Volumes/Projects/com.github/adhara/vue/fw/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:138:17)
    at createPluginDescriptors.next (<anonymous>)
    at /Volumes/Projects/com.github/adhara/vue/fw/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:94:32
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/Volumes/Projects/com.github/adhara/vue/fw/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/gensync-utils/async.js:24:3)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at evaluateSync (/Volumes/Projects/com.github/adhara/vue/fw/node_modules/gensync/index.js:251:28)
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 file.js   |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 script.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   1 passed, 1 total
Time:        3.02 s
Ran all test suites.
```

So in first case, tests are running but coverage no.
And in second case, tests and coverage works but an error is thrown.